# Android - Disclaimer popping up after every intent

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Just a bit about my app first. Its a quiz app. It has a main screen displaying a question, which loads straight away, and arrows going `previous` and `next` which go to other quiz questions. I'm using the same layout over and over, just by passing different question data, so when I click the "next" button, it will just launch an `intent` to the same class, just with different data. At the start of my one single layout, I have a little check to see if the user has clicked to hide the disclaimer or not.

So my disclaimer pops up at the start of the app. It has a `dismiss` button and a `Dont show this again` checkbox. I can get the checkbox working perfect, using `SharedPreferences` but the problem arises when they hit the `Dismiss` button. Since I'm reusing the same layout, any time the user navigates to a new question, the disclaimer pops up. I only want it to popup on the first screen, e.g. when the app loads.

I have tried setting another `SharedPreference`  to hide the disclaimer when the user hits `dismiss` but once I hide it, it never comes back, because when the user loads the app back up again, that shared preference is still set. My problem is knowing where to set the preference back! I tried resetting it in `onPause()` but that didn't work.

So, what I'm asking is, how can I determine if an activity is the first one to be loaded so I can only do the Disclaimer check then, and not in each of the subsequent screens?

Thanks.

EDIT: Here's my `OnCreate()` method:

```
final static String disclaimerShownPref = "disclaimerShown";
final static String disclaimerShownOnce = "disclaimerShownThisSession";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    //Checks to see if the boolean is set
    //The second argument is the default to use if the preference can't be found
    if(!mPrefs.getBoolean(disclaimerShownPref, false))
    {
        if(!mPrefs.getBoolean(disclaimerShownOnce, true))
        {
            new Disclaimer(this);
        }
    }

    topMostLayout=buildHomeScreen();
    setContentView(topMostLayout);
}
```

Comment: can you post the code of your activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case I would suggest using a static variable in your activity:

```
private static boolean sFirstTime = true;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    if( sFirstTime )
    {
        /*
         * Place the disclaimer check here 
         */
        sFirstTime = false;
    }
    else
    {

    }
```

Having said that. I would consider a better approach to switch between questions in the same instance of your activity instead of creating a new one every time.

Good luck!

Comment: The static variable way does seem the best, now that I think of it. Must be my inexperience showing that I didn't think of it!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of restarting the activity each time the user navigates between questions, you should just write a function that will repopulate the views with the new question data when previous or next are clicked. As for the disclaimer, if you want it to show up every time the app is started, then setting the variable using shared preferences is not the best way to go about it. The shared preferences are not deleted when the app closes, they are only deleted if you erase them manually or uninstall the application altogether. Instead create a variable in your activity that tracks whether or not "Dismiss" was clicked. As long as the app is running the dialog will not be displayed, but when the app is restarted all the variables including the one that keeps track of displaying the dialog will be reset and it will show up again.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I was going to do this, but I wanted the animated effect that launching the intent gives. That's solely why I chose this method. Because otherwise it might not be crystal clear to the user that the question has changed.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an Intent to launch a new version of your activity, why not just use an onClickListener to call setText() and change the display question? This might make the Activity lifecycle more intuitive and probably simplify your code.

Comment: The reason for this is because I want the animation to show the user that the new question has been displayed. Otherwise it seems too quick and they may not realise the question has changed.